# Do we have $\partial_x(u(x,0)) = (\partial_xu) (x,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given a differentiable function $u : (x,y)\in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto u(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$, with $\Omega$ an open set, do we have the following identity?

$$ (\partial_xu)(x,0) :=\bigg(\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}\bigg) \bigg|_{y=0} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x+h,0)-u(x,0)}{h} := \partial_x(u(x,0))$$

Intuitively, yes, because $y$ is "fixed" in the definition of partial derivative with respect to $x$. But I am confused about how to formally prove this identity.

Comment: This is a tautology. Think about how 'plugging y=0' into an expression is defined.

Comment: It probably helps to prove the identity by writing it out using the $\varepsilon - \delta$ argument.